# how to display the vf page which has been included in the custom console component

Tags: visualforce, custom-console-components

I have a custom object and in that custom object layout i have added a vf page to the custom console component in the right side bar of style with widht 20%.
Now i need to make the below circle in center.

Screenshot:
[image: I need to place this circle in center]

Help me out guys !!

Comment: What have you written so far? And what do you mean 'Now i need to make the below circle in center.'? Do you want a static green circle on that page? I assume not.

Comment: I want that green circle to be displayed in the center of the component !! Thats it

Comment: But the green circle is to be dynamic? The value '4' will change to '10' if there are 10 records of the custom object on the page?

Comment: It is just a field value from the current record. it is jus for display , nothing to do with the circle. Just i want to display that in center

Comment: Just use the apex:image attribute: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_image.htm